# Is there a way to shift an image in fourier space without the shifted part sliding from the other side? (python)

Tags: python, opencv, fft, scikit-image, shift

Functions that shift in the fourier space, slides the image into itself (as in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.fourier_shift.html)

Is there a way in fourier space that shifts the image but fills the remaining pixels after the shift, black or white, instead of sliding the image? (as in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.shift.html but it should be in fourier space)
[shifted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmmX8.png)

Comment: Just pad the image before transforming to the frequency space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Don't you think padding will change the image properties?

Comment: Pad, FFT, apply phase rotation, IFFT, crop. There is no other way if you want to do this through the Fourier transform.

Comment: fourier transforms assume periodic signals, hence the "roll". -- fourier and state space "mirror" each other, kinda. if you wanted to "erase" a part of fourier space (**band pass/stop**), you'd convolve with a suitable kernel in state space (or do it twice and subtract, difference of gaussians, you know). it would make sense to me that you could swap the operations and spaces: if you wanted to erase some part in state space (looks like band pass/stop except _not_ in fourier space) you *could* try convolving in fourier space. I haven't done that but it would make sense to me.

Comment: however, convolution is an expensive operation, if not done as fft + multiplication + ifft, and *that* would just be masking out the area you want gone. so you've gained nothing, unless you **really** need to do this in fourier space.

Comment: Fourier space modification allows high quality resampling of fractional pixel shifts (similar to Sinc interpolation).

Comment: If this is the purely conceptual question that it appears to be, perhaps https://math.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want circular convolution or circular shifts in the result when doing IFFT(FFT()) modifications, you can zero-pad (or use other colors/textures of padding) the borders of the original 2D vector by the amount of the shift (M+N-1), and crop as needed afterwards.